# Error MSB3027: Could not copy "/src/app/obj/Debug/net6.0/apphost" to "bin/Debug/net6.0/lucky-music". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed

Tags: .net, xunit

I'm running a .net's unit test (with xunit) in my docker container. Unfortunately, it results with this error:

```
Error MSB3027: Could not copy "/src/app/obj/Debug/net6.0/apphost" to "bin/Debug/net6.0/lucky-music". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix that worked for me was to remove `obj`, `bin` and `out` directories at locations where my `*.csproj` resides prior to running my unit test.

```sh
rm -rf /src/app/obj/ \
    /src/app/out/ \
    /src/app/bin/ \
    /src/tests/obj/ \
    /src/tests/out/ \
    /src/tests/bin/
```